# XABP and WCF wsHttpBinding

Tags: iis-7, wcf-wshttpbinding

How can I use WCF wsHttpBinding on my WPF Browser application?

Answer (score 0):

It works normally as it is on Windows application project and ASP.Net application. You just need to add ServiceReference to your xbap project pointing to your wcf service and Visual Studio will automatically generate the bindings (of wsHttpBinding type) and client endpoint pointing to your service on the app.config (xbap also uses app.config).

Then on your xbap page's codebehind, just do the usual coduing on consuming WCF services.